# Adding Qt Widgets to MainWindow at Run Time

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Here is my situation:

I'm developing a C++ application in Creator/Designer with Qt 5.6 on Windows 7 64-bit

I'm designing a skeleton GUI that doesn't do much on its own. It mainly provides a mechanism to integrate engineering tools built by other developers (Plug-ins if you will, not to be confused Plug-ins to Qt itself). The skeleton will be installed on workstations around the office, and it should be able to pull these Plug-ins from a network location and install them to the skeleton *without recompiling.* On startup, the skeleton should read its list of Plug-ins and build its menus, toolbars, and UI Widgets accordingly.

So the question is ultimately this: **Does Qt provide a way of adding .ui files *and associated code* to a QMainWindow at run time?**

Can it do so in such a way that the skeleton will not have to be changed, recompiled, and re-deployed whenever new Plug-ins are created?

**Close, but no cigar:** Here is an [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-calculatorbuilder-example.html) of a calculator UI created in Designer being pulled into another program dynamically, but it appears this method uses the .ui file *only*. In other words, the boxes and buttons are pulled from the .ui file, but its logic is implemented in the "skeleton." I need to do something akin to embedding the calculator as its own fully functional Widget at run time.

Side question: If there isn't a nice mechanism provided by Qt, are there disadvantages to having the other developers compile their Plug-ins as DLLs for my particular case?

Comment: Do you insist on `.ui` files? All the "new" stuff is QML, so I'd gather it'd be better to have some sort of skeleton description of the plugin UI through either code (bound to the plugin interface) or another specific metafile. Then you can pull all the information you need (what kind of button, where it should go, what it should do, etc.) in your "skeleton" and always have it work.

Comment: Admittedly, I'm pretty new to Qt. I'm not married to `.ui` files themselves, but I would prefer that the other developers use Designer as much as possible to make their Plug-ins. As I understand it, Designer just speaks `.ui`

Comment: How are those other developers going to develop the logic for their UIs? C++ code?

Comment: Yes, definitely C++ code

Comment: So why not just using an ordinary plugin system? Define a plugin interface (say, a plugin exposes a method that returns its QWidget), your main app just loads the available plugins, your designers create them.

Comment: I may. Like I say in the side question, my alternative is to use DLLs. I just wanted to know if Qt had a mechanism for sharing Widgets at run time, since I noticed it accommodates it with `.ui` files

Comment: `.ui` files just specify which widgets to create, and some properties of them. They don't bring logic. You'll need extra ways of specifying such logic (scripting, C++ plugins, ...).

Comment: I'm aware of that - see the original question. 
In the end, I found the `QtPlugin` class and its associated macros. I believe this is what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some basic misunderstanding of what a Qt application does. Every single widget you're seeing is instantiated by executing C++ code - it is all done dynamically, at runtime. The uic takes a `foo.ui` file and turns it into `ui_foo.h`. That defines a class that can populate a base widget with children.

You can use the `QUiLoader` to parse a `.ui` file and instantiate its objects at runtime, but there's little point to doing that since the other code is still C++, so it's simplest to have a plugin project that converts `.ui` files into C++, then compiles those along your other code and links them into a plugin dll.

The plugins are simply `.dll`s, ideally providing functionality consumable by the Qt plugin system, that have all the code needed: the code the comes from `.ui` files via uic, and the code the plugin authors wrote by hand. A plugin is an object factory: it will create `QObject` instance(s) that can then provide your skeleton with all the widgets and other objects it needs.

That's all. The plugins are `.dll`s, and you're of course free to download them from a network location to a cache folder, and open them at runtime.

There's no difference between plugins "to Qt itself" and plugins to your application: Qt is C++ code, just as your application is. While it can consume the functionality of some plugins, the rest of them are for your code to consume.

For inspiration, you should look at the sources of Qt Creator itself. It is a completely plugin-based application, the core is a plugin container that doesn't do much. Probably you could reuse the Qt Creator core as the basis for your application, with either no changes or very minimal changes. It would come with a network discovery plugin that gets the remaining plugins from the server and into the cache, and then loads them up. Such a plugin can be probably written in 150 lines of code, excluding the minimal boilerplate :)